# How to display a already defined datatable in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a regular datatable created, it exports and imports into xml and everything is fine.

To make easy its acess, i created a datagridview, and i'm trying to make the dataatable content available there

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.DataSource = DataAccess.Instance.tabelaEC0;
    }
```

(i got the table created in a different class so it would be available to all forms)

all i get is a empty gridview

Comment: Please give some details on DataAccess.Instance.tabelaEC0. How do you initialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of setting a DataSource on DataGridView. DataSet1 is a typed dataset with one table "DataTable1" having one string column:

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
ds.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row("test");
dataGridView1.DataMember = "DataTable1";
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Alternatively you can bind a table as DataSource:

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
ds.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row("test");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DataTable1;
```

Comment: The binding worked, but not the 1st example, you created a dataset, added a table, and then defined the source correct?

Comment: @CésarAmorim, I didn't quite understand the question. The both code snippets work for me. Could you please specify what error you get with the 1st example?

Comment: the question was this: on both examples you created a dataset    ds    and added a row named    test    , and only then you executed the code to display the datatable on the grid, correct? About the error, it simply displays nothing, i used    `dataGridView1.DataMember = "nameofthetable";`     and    `dataGridView1.DataSource = nameofthedataset;`     here's a picture of it. Anyways, i changed before trying, i used a class to define the dataset and the datatables so they would be available to everyform, i'm having some trouble cause i can't modify its values correctly, wanna take a look?